# Get value of parse JSON from php array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

```
$query = "SELECT Item_Name from item_details";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $optionValue[] = "<option value='" . $row['Item_Name'] . "'>" . $row['Item_Name'] . "</option>";
}

$query1 = "SELECT Item_Name from item_addon";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $optionValue1[] = "<option value='" . $row['Item_Name'] . "'>" . $row['Item_Name'] . "</option>";
}

return json_encode(array("a" => $optionValue, "b" => $optionValue1));
```

I need to parse the data of `a` and `b`

```
optionDetails = $.parseJSON(data);

for (i = 0; i < optionDetails.length; i++) {
    det_item_name = optionDetails[i];
    $('#det_item_name').append(det_item_name);
}

optionAdd = $.parseJSON(data)
for (i = 0; i < optionAdd.length; i++) {
    det_item_name = optionAdd[i];

    $('#add_name').append(add_name);
}
```

How do I parse the data of `a` and `b` in `optionDetails` and `optionAdd` ?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're doing parsing the data? Did you log `data` to see what it contains, we have no idea since you didn't post any of the code that gets the JSON from PHP

Comment: it looks like you're using jQuery, if you are doing an AJAX call to your `php` file's data use `$.getJSON` and it should automatically parse the response into `JSON` for you so that you should just be able to use something like `data.a` and `data.b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
var json_array = $.parseJSON(data);
var optionDetails = json_array.a;

for (i = 0; i < optionDetails.length; i++) {
    det_item_name = optionDetails[i];
    $('#det_item_name').append(det_item_name);


}

var optionAdd = json_array.b;
for (i = 0; i < optionAdd.length; i++) {
    det_item_name = optionAdd[i];

    $('#add_name').append(add_name);

}
```